# Pre and Post Migration - Calling External Scripts - liquibase

Tags: liquibase

is there a way of calling external scripts with liquibase in a staged manner?

I am looking for something similar to flyway callbacks to call external scripts like sh: https://flywaydb.org/documentation/callbacks.html

Example:

1) pre-migration: run sh script 1

2) run migration

3) post-migration: run sh script 2

4) If migration fails: run sh script 3

Basically a staged mechanism of calling external scripts as part of the migration steps.

I would appreciate your feedback.

Thank you

Tobi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can run external programs (including sh scripts) with http://www.liquibase.org/documentation/changes/execute_command.html

If you want to run something before and after each migration run, you need to structure your master changelog such way:

```
    <changeSet id="preMigration" runAllways="true">
    ...pre migration
    </changeSet>

    ...all your migrations are here

    <changeSet id="postMigration" runAllways="true">
    ...post migration
    </changeSet>
```

And I'm not sure that there is error handler.

Comment: Just a small correction here, 'runAllways'  is not an attribute, replace it with 'runAlways'

Answer (score 0):

Thank you dbf

I was able to run a bat file using liquibase and pass parameters into it:

```
<property name="my_param_name" value="myValue"/>

<changeSet author="tobi" id="preMigration" >
    <executeCommand executable="C:\projects\lbdemo\trunk\mybatfile.bat">
      <arg value="Constant: ${my_param_name}"/>
    </executeCommand>  
</changeSet>
```

C:\projects\lbdemo\trunk\mybatfile.bat :

```
@echo off
  if not exist "C:\Test\" mkdir C:\Test
  set arg1=%1
  (echo %arg1%) > C:\Test\EmptyFile.txt
```

mybatfile.bat will create an EmptyFile.txt and write the my_param_name value into it.